# Bluemix custom service brokers

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, private-cloud

I'm trying to find out how to publish custom service brokers using Bluemix Dedicated or Local. Is it possible? If yes, is it allowed to customers or only to IBM support?

Comment: Check out the cloudfoundry [docs on custom services](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/). Note it says "You must have admin access to your CF instance to manage service brokers and the services marketplace catalog."

Comment: Contact IBM, currently you require a specific tool (CF CLI wrapper) not documented in public documentation yet. But it is possible with it.

Answer (score 0):

Registering a custom service broker with Bluemix Dedicated or Bluemix Local is documented now. I found it when researching another topic: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/index.html#oc_catalog

Service Brokers for a single service can be added using the GUI, advanced brokers need to be added using the CLI. The recommendation is to use the bluemix admin plugin for the command line interface.